# Jquery finds no elements after click unless first alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

Using the Firefox browser console I'm trying to select an element in an i-frame. The i-frame is shown in a modal dialog which opens when I click a link.

This example code below does the following:

1. Click the first link on page which opens a modal dialog
2. Show alert
3. Once I close the alert, the code finds all span elements with class
4. Code then prints the number of span elements found.

This code works at this link:
`https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/q=%2522food%2520and%2520drug%2522`

```
$('.preview-file').eq(1).trigger('click');
alert("close this alert");
previewFrame = $('#ipreviewer');
all = $(previewFrame).contents().find(".sect-efts-search-match-khjdickkwg");
console.log($(all).length);
```

But, when I take out the `alert("close this alert")`, the code no longer works. Without the alert the code does not find any span elements and prints `0` to the console.

nonworking code (returns 0):

```
$('.preview-file').eq(1).trigger('click');
previewFrame = $('#ipreviewer');
all = $(previewFrame).contents().find(".sect-efts-search-match-khjdickkwg");
console.log($(all).length);
```

Why doesn't this code work without the alert? How can I fix this?

Edit:
I tried a while loop to see if I had to wait for something to load, but it also did not work (never-ending loop).

```
$('.preview-file').eq(i).trigger('click');
previewFrame = $('#ipreviewer');
all = $(previewFrame).contents().find(".sect-efts-search-match-khjdickkwg");
console.log($(all).length);
while($(all).length < 1){
    previewFrame = $('#ipreviewer');
  all = $(previewFrame).contents().find(".sect-efts-search-match-khjdickkwg");
  console.log($(all).length);
  
}
```

Comment: `$('#ipreviewer')` doesn't exist when page is loaded and seems is inserted when modal is opened. Simple approach would be a reasonably long setTimeout. More advanced would be use a MutationObserver to get a reference to the previewer but also want time for it to load the internal window also

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added an edit. I tried a while loop, which keeps checking if number of span elements is more than zero. But it did not work. I think this should be similar to setting a time delay?

Comment: But first problem is that `$('#ipreviewer')` needs to exist and get loaded  before you can look inside it with `contents() and find()

Comment: If I keep checking for ```$('#ipreviewer')``` in a while loop shouldn't it eventually exist?

Comment: Yes....need to use a `length` check. Rather than in a while loop I would use a setInterval and clear that interval once you have a reference to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iframe doesn't exist on initial page load

Here's an approach you can play with that uses `setInterval()` to check for existince of the iframe and items inside the iframe that for me is returning a count of four items found

```
const timer = setInterval(function(){
  const $frme=$('#ipreviewer');
  // check if frame exists
  if($('#ipreviewer').length){
    const $items = $frme.contents().find(".sect-efts-search-match-khjdickkwg");
    // check if items found
    if($items.length){
      // do something with the items
      console.log('Found ', $items.length, ' items');
      // clear interval timer when found
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }else{
    console.log('Not found')
  }
},100)// 1/10th second intervals

$('.preview-file').eq(1).trigger('click');
```

Comment: This seems to only work once, if I try to iterate or even if I try to run the function twice it fails . For example running on eq(1) and then eq(2) fails. 
```
$('.preview-file').eq(1).trigger('click');

$('.preview-file').eq(2).trigger('click');
```

Comment: You won't be able to do next click immediately. Keep in mind it takes time for an iframe to load a new page